# Please reopen this erroneous closure as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Contain the Georgian Triangle and Southwestern Ontario any 'drive-through' parks or wildlife areas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55496/13759) was unilaterally closed as a duplicate of [Does Central Ontario contain any 'drive-through' national parks or wildlife areas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55493/13759), but these two questions' fully disjoint areas of focus prove their complete difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just voted to reopen. The geographical areas are distinct and thus justify the need for two separate questions. I'm guessing that Ankur acted too rapidly. It happens, mods are humans after all.

Comment: Whoops my bad. @mindcorrosive has reopened.